# How to remove the Added widget within that widget?

Tags: python-3.x, widget, kivy

how can I remove the added widget from within that widget. am i making any sense? hopefully yes, hehehe...

anyway the simple code consist of buttons and label only.
My aim is if I click the add button it will show the widget which is a label & button. If i want to remove the widget i'll just click the close button in that widget.

but its not closing, its been two days already and i cant find whats the problem and its not giving me any error.

Thanks guys.

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_file = Builder.load_string('''
<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            on_release: root.add_button(True)
            text: 'ADD'
            size_hint: .2,.2

<Layout1>:
    BoxLayout:
        pos: self.x,300
        size_hint: .5,.3
        Label:
            text: 'THIS IS A ADDED WIDGET'
        Button:
            text: 'Close'
            on_release: root.closeBTN()
    ''')

class Layout1(FloatLayout):
    def closeBTN(self):
        AddWidget_Layout1().addEmps(True)

class AddWidget_Layout1(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddWidget_Layout1,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.count = 0
        self.layout1 = Layout1()

    def addEmps(self,xadd):
        if xadd == 1:
            self.add_widget(self.layout1)
        elif xadd == True:
            self.remove_widget(self.layout1)


class Screen1(Screen,AddWidget_Layout1):
    def add_button(self,*args):
        self.count += 1
        print
        if self.count == 1:
            self.addEmps(1)

class projectApps(App):
    def build(self):
        return SM

SM = ScreenManager()
SM.add_widget(Screen1())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    projectApps().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few bugs in your code, first, you are testing xadd for 1 and True which is kinda the same thing:

```
def addEmps(self,xadd):
    if xadd:
        self.add_widget(self.layout1)
    else: #was elif xadd == True which cannot happen...
        self.remove_widget(self.layout1)
```

I would also change:

```
def closeBTN(self):
    #AddWidget_Layout1().addEmps(True) #BAD! will create a new instance
    self.parent.addEmps(False) # this looks better
```

Finally, I'm not sure why are you doing this since you are already using **ScreenManager**, so you can just switch to a different screen whenever you need instead of doing this weird widget removal thing ...

I hope this clears most of the issues

Comment: the Idea here is that instead of creating another screen for a FORMS, ill just create a widget FORMS.

but the thing is that if the variable xadd is True, the widget is  not being remove. If it where to show error/bug, i might find solution. but there's no error showing.

Comment: @azura - Look at my anwser, 1 and True are the same in python use False to remove the layout...

Comment: great it work, this is what i need, sweet.... before, i did change the True to False but it wasn't working. i didn't notice self.parent, i need to check python docu regarding self.parent.. im just wandering how can python knew the function addEmps located at? in which the class/parent. ill definitely need to check the python documentation... great!! thank Yoav!